# 401 Unauthorized : WebApi UseOAuthBearerAuthentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am starting with authentication. So I created a WebApi and tried to protect it using bearer token. I added the following code in the configuration method in startup class:

```
    string clientId = "76dd292c-8522-40d8-b0df-09e6c3300498";
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = clientId,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")),
        });
    }
```

On the client, I have the following code:

```
var clientId =  "76dd292c-8522-40d8-b0df-09e6c3300498";
PublicClientApplication client = new PublicClientApplication(clientId) {
            UserTokenCache=new FileCache()
};
var result = client.AcquireTokenAsync(new string[] { clientId }).Result; 
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.Token);

var res=httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44321/Api/Values").Result;
```

I am getting 401 unauthorized. I downloaded the sample code from https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebAPI-Bearer-DotNet/archive/complete.zip
and pointed my client to this service. and it works fine. I compared the code and its the same. I am trying to understand what could be the issue. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Take a look at the response, you will probably find a more detailed error information there.

Comment: Apologies. Forgot to mention it. The response has the following message: Authorization has been denied for this request

Comment: Try to trace the request with fiddler, aad usually provides more information.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Just wondering if this is an AAD issue. But still took fiddler, on the AAD calls, I am not seeing any errors.

Comment: Pretty interesting. Compared all the packages and made the version of the nuget packages the same and it worked. So on higher version of the nuget packages, it seems to be throwing 401 unauthorized. Cant believe spent so much time on this.